# Apache crashes when php_apc extension is turned on when using symfony?

Tags: php, apache, apc

It's happenning in windows.

PHP5.3.0

Apache2.2.11

Symfony 1.4.1

Is there a fix ?

```
[apc-error] Cannot redeclare class sfeventdispatcher in D:\wamp\symfony-1.4.1\lib\event_dispatcher\sfEventDispatcher.php on line 3.
[crit] Parent: child process exited with status 2 -- Aborting.
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be related to http://pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=16860
Which version of apc do you use?

Comment: I downloaded from here:http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ .I can't remember whether I downloaded Win32 or Win32-ntf,it's in my office.

Comment: But the question still remains :"Which version" ;-)  I see php_apc-3.0.19-5.2..., php_apc-3.1-5-3... and two php_apc-5.3-svn... versions on that page.

Comment: php_apc-5.3-svn20091115-vc6-x86.zip,I'm now sure the version I downloaded is correct.I don't know if it's a symfony bug or extension bug.

Comment: Oh fixed by `apc.canonicalize=0`,so must be bug of the apc itself.